Convert string into list of dictionaries in python
Used this site a bunch, but this is my first post.  Thanks, in advance, to anyone who might be able to offer advice!
I'm using Python3 to read an excel file.  I have a bunch of cells that contain data that looks like either A) a dictionary or B) a list of dictionaries.
These are being imported as string objects in Python and I can't seem to convert them to dictionaries or lists of dictionaries.  I've tried json.loads() and keep getting an error
Here is an example of the text in the string object:
[{'event': 'PUBLIC_ACCESS_CHANGED', 'timeOccurred': '2022-11-02T14:21:09.000-05:00'}, {'event': 'DISPOSITION_SUBMITTED', 'status': 'Approved as Amended', 'comments': '', 'timeOccurred': '2022-11-02T16:22:32.000-05:00'}, {'event': 'NOTE_SUBMITTED', 'subject': 'This is a subject line.', 'comments': 'User,\r\n\r\nThis is a note that was submitted.\r\n\r\nThanks,\r\nNote Author', 'timeOccurred': '2022-10-26T14:00:37.000-05:00', 'userSubmitted': 'Note Author'}]

I even tried replacing the single quotes with double ones to get json.loads() to work, but it doesn't seem to.
Here is the json.loads() error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-3162c498c23f> in <module>
     14     #print(endoffield)
     15     field_messages = templist[0]
---> 16     newfield = json.loads(field_messages)
     17 
     18     print('this is type(field_messages)', type(field_messages))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Here is the code I was running:
for excelrow in ws_case.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=last_row, min_col=1, max_col=last_col, values_only=True):
    
    templist = list(excelrow[95:146]) # create temp list for current Excel row with just the fields I need
    field_casekey = excelrow[0] # grab the ID for the excel record 
    field_messages = templist[0] # load the field to a variable
    print('this is type(field_messages):', type(field_messages))
    print('this is field_messages:', field_messages)
    newfield = json.loads(field_messages)

Here was the output before the error threw:
this is type(field_messages): <class 'str'>

this is field_messages: [{'event': 'PUBLIC_ACCESS_CHANGED', 'timeOccurred': '2022-11-02T14:21:09.000-05:00'}, {'event': 'DISPOSITION_SUBMITTED', 'status': 'Approved as Amended', 'comments': '', 'timeOccurred': '2022-11-02T16:22:32.000-05:00'}, {'event': 'NOTE_SUBMITTED', 'subject': 'This is a subject line.', 'comments': 'User,\r\n\r\nThis is a note that was submitted.\r\n\r\nThanks,\r\nNote Author', 'timeOccurred': '2022-10-26T14:00:37.000-05:00', 'userSubmitted': 'Note Author'}]


This looks like a Python repr. You'd have to find what generating this string and change that end to use a proper serializer. It will be difficult to do this thoroughly without using eval otherwise.

Here is the code I was running: No, the error traceback does not match that code.  Please post the actual code.

This code works for me, after changing single-quotes to double-quotes and escaping the embedded \r\n characters.  So your actual string must be different than what you have shown here.

@JohnGordon "escaping the embedded \r\n characters" - That's a given since OP's showing the contents of the string, not the string itself. That said, the error still doesn't seem to match the data. You'd get that error from an empty string or non-JSON syntax.

To be clear, there's an existing question that covers what you're trying to do with this data, but like John said, this example isn't totally consistent, and, like Wim said, if this data is in fact a Python repr, it'd be better to switch the code further up the chain to output to a proper serialization format, like JSON for example.
